# How to generalize over these morphological rules?

Tags: morphology, morphological-analysis

I've just started a linguistic course at university, we've just started Morphology this week. 
I am very new to the subject and I am looking for some guidance about how to approach a morphology exercise. I already studied the basic vocabulary and now I am trying to figure out how to solve practically this exercise. Being new to the topic, I find it really hard to understand what I am really suppose to do.

About question a:
I tried to analyse the material and examples I had, reasoning this way.

**HIS** (3rd person singular, genitive)

I compared the different forms and I could assume these rules. 
1) When a word starts with p and ends with u, starts with k and ends with a or starts with t and ends with a, I usually add s- at the beginning and -be at the end, and I get this "his ...(word)...". 
Examples: 
palu *s*palu*be*
ku:ba *s*ku:ba*be*
tapa *s*tapa*be*
2)But if a word starts with g, then I need to add a s- at the beginning and also change the g into a k, adding at the end be like in the previous case. 
If a word start with b, then I will have s- at the beginning, followed by p (the b turned into a p), with -be at the very end. 
And if a word starts with d, then I have s- at the beginning, followed by t with -be at the end.

These are the "rules" I could observe from the examples given.

**YOUR** (2nd person singular, genitive)

In the cases of words that start with p and ends with u, starts with k ad ends with a, starts with t and ends with a, I get "your ..(word)..." form, adding a s- at the beginning and a -lu at the end of the word. 
With words that have g at the beginning I will have a s- a the beginning, the g turns into a k, and lu at the end. 
With words that have b at the beginning I will have a s- at the beginning, the b turns into a p, and lu at the end.
With words that have d at the beginning I will have s- at the beginning, the d turns into t and lu at the end.

SO, I found soooooo many rules to explain how to make a genitive form of a word in these language, how can I identify one common rule? Is there a way of simplifying this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE! I changed your title to a more suitable format, if you don't mind.

Comment: Voiced stops in your data (b, d, g) are **assimilated in voice** to the voiceless possessive morpheme, s, and then you have two morphemes, be (3SG) and lu (2PL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have actually answered your question.

According to the examples given, possessive is formed with the following pattern:

- 3<sup>rd</sup> person Singular: `s` + root + `be`
- 2<sup>nd</sup> person Plural: `s` + root + `lu`
- Plus, voiced `b/d/g` in the 1st syllable of the root becomes voiceless `p/t/k`.

You must be confused with unability to tell whether or not the vowel matters here. The examples *do not provide* sufficient information to judge whether or not the vowel plays any role. Simply because there are no consistency: `pa*/ta*/ku:*` cant be compared to `be*/do*/ge*`.

In order to make sure, ask your teacher to provide with samples starting with:

- `pe*/po*/pu:*`,
- `te*/to*/tu:*`,
- `ka*/ke*/ko*`,
- `ba*/bo*/bu:*`,
- `da*/de*/du:*`,
- `ga*/go*/gu:*`, respectively.

Hence, all possible initial consonants (6 ones) and all possible vowels (4), minus six existing combinations = 6 * 4 - 6 = 18.

Having 18 additional examples, you will be able to tell whether or not the vowel matters.

With only 6 examples, the simplest rule applies, *vowel does not matter*.